# Remove trailing slash from a link in JS or in ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following HTML.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li>
   <a href="/florida-villas/" itemprop="item">Florida</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="/florida-villas/orlando-villas/">Orlando</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="/florida-villas/orlando-villas/davenport-lakes">Davenport Lakes</li>
</ol>
```

I am wanting to remove only the trailing slash and not both slashes within the a tag. So, it would look like this.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li>
   <a href="/florida-villas" itemprop="item">Florida</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="/florida-villas/orlando-villas">Orlando</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="/florida-villas/orlando-villas/davenport-lakes">Davenport Lakes</li>
</ol>
```

I have looked around online and have this so far, but this removes all slashes. How can I just choose the last one?

```
$('.breadcrumb li').each(function(e){
    var str = $(this).html();
    var replaced_text = str.replace(/\//g,'', "$1");
    $(this).html(replaced_text);
});
```

Any help would be amazing. The site is built in ASP.Net.

The current code is: (I cannot do ASP, so that is why I am trying to do it in jQuery), unless this is easy to do directly in the code below.

```
@{
var linksInTotal = Request.Url.Segments.Count();
var crumbUrl = "/";

<ol class="breadcrumb">

    @for (var i = 2; i < linksInTotal; i++)
    {
        var link = Request.Url.Segments[i];
        crumbUrl += link;
        <li>
            @if (i < linksInTotal - 1)
            {
                <a href="@crumbUrl.ToLower()">
                    @HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link.Replace("-", " ").Replace("villas"," ").Replace("/", "").ToTitleCase())

                </a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="">
                    @HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link.Replace("-", " ").Replace("villas", " ").Replace("/", "").ToTitleCase())
                </a>
            }
            @if (i < linksInTotal - 1)
            {
                <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            }
            <meta itemprop="position" content="@i" />
        </li>
    }
</ol>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on the page itself with `TrimEnd('/')`

```
@HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link.Replace("-", " ").Replace("villas", " ").Replace("/", "").ToTitleCase().TrimEnd('/'))
```

Comment: I had literally just found this in the code on another page. Thanks.